# Java Reflection: create a constructor for an abstract class

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, abstract

If I have this class that I cannot modify...

```
public abstract class AClass {
    Object value;
    public AClass(Object value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Then how would I create an instance of it with reflection?
This...

```
Class<?> clazz = // some class
Constructor</*someClass*/> constructor = AClass.class.getConstructor(clazz);
Object key = clazz.getConstructor(Object.class).newInstance(/*something*/);
/*someClassResult */ result = constructor.newInstance(key);
```

throws an InstantiationException at the last line.

Comment: You can't instantiate an abstract class, you'll need to instantiate a concrete implementation of the abstract class.

Comment: Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. Full stop. Reflection cannot get around that intentional limitation. You'll need a concrete (i.e. non-abstract) class that inherits from your abstract class. Even if you can't modify the abstract class you should still be able to write a concrete subclass. At worst, you can generate and compile a class a run-time but I doubt that much effort is required in your case.

Comment: Just create a subclass with empty implementations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instantiate any class, even abstract classes using sun.misc.Unsafe .
Example:

```
Field theunsafeField = 
Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
theunsafeField.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) theunsafeField.get(null);
AClass aclazz = (AClass) unsafe.allocateInstance(AClass.class);
```

Otherwise you can create a little class which extends AClass, and then you can instantiate your implementation

Comment: Thanks! Never knew about Unsafe, will look into that later.

Comment: If my answer has been useful, consider upvoting it pls

Comment: Oh yeah, sure thing